# Real reason for adding DROP in CREATE Stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I just wanted to know what is the best practice to create and execute a stored procedure.

I have seen like below:-

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'Foo')
  DROP PROCEDURE Foo
  GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo
```

But I am thinking when we execute this stored procedure, it will drop the stored procedure and create a new one. But if there is error in the create stored procedure syntax, it won't recreate the stored procedure, right? So as a result our existing stored procedure is deleted and new stored procedure is not created. So what is the real reason for adding DROP here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is so that your scripts can be run in an [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) way - they can be run as many times as needed, with the same result. Namely, your database will have the stored procedure you desire. Your procedure will be created, and dropped beforehand if needed. If you didn't do this, then you'd need separate drop and create scripts.

If you're concerned that your scripts have errors, well, fix them. Run your scripts a few times, and fix any problems that arise. The effort is worth not having to maintain separate sets of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

BECAUSE it is execute in line by line manner so when it create procedure and then error comes and again you recreate that procedure then it gives error because it is already generated in your database with error code....

so for this it want recreate that procedure again.....

you can use alter instead of create....

Hope this help you...